# Stuck on my server root folder, robots.txt file not deleting

Tags: robots.txt

I remove robots.txt file in my server root but google can't delete that.
Webmastertool to create robotx.txt file

How can I remove or disable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WordPress generate a dynamic robots.txt which does not physically exists. To remove/disable it you have two options:

**Option 1**: Remove `do_robots` action in your theme functions.php or plugin

```
remove_action('do_robots', 'do_robots');
```

The action `do_robots` is still available to be added again by other plugins.

**Option 2**: Create a real robots.txt file, put it the root folder of your site. This will stop WordPress (or plugins) auto generate its own.

Comment: Hey cybmeta i add that a functions.php remove_action('do_robots', 'do_robots'); follow your step but can remove robots.txt file :( i am stuck

Comment: its take much time?

Comment: Is robots.txt physically exists in your server? If so, as explained in the answer, removing the action won't work. Also, if you remove the action and later a plugin execute it again the robots.txt will be generated anyway. Disable all plugins and use a core theme to see if there is any plugin generating the file or go with the option 2 and create your own robots.txt in the server.